# Extjs4 treenodes click error

Tags: extjs4, treepanel

i am working in extjs4. i have created treeview as-

```
Ext.define('Balaee.view.qb.qbquestion.tree1', {

    extend: 'Ext.tree.Panel',
    title: 'Simple Tree',
    width: 200,
   id:'tree1',
    height: 150,

    alias : 'widget.tree1',
    store:'qb.qbquestionStore',
    displayField: 'text',
    rootVisible : true,
    multiSelect : true,
    valueField:'id',
    renderTo: Ext.getBody(),}),
```

Json send via server gets properly attached to above treepanel. But whwn i am trying to click on treenodes its giving me error as "TypeError: listener.fireFn is undefined" in mozilla firefox and error as "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'apply' of undefined " in chrome. Also nodes are being expanded only once.
In controller for itemclick, i have written code as-

```
init : function() {
        this.control({
                'tree1':{
                     itemclick: {

                           fn: function (view, record, item, index, e) {

                           if(record.data.checked==true)
                               {
                                  console.log(record.data.id);   

                               }
                           }
                       },
```

So what changes i need to do to remove error?

Answer (score 0):

`'tree1'` is an incorrect selector. In order to attach an event handler to component by its id prepend id with hashtag `#`:

```js
this.control({
    '#tree1':{
```

### UPDATE

I missed line `alias : 'widget.tree1'`. Therefore your selector was correct.

Try to change listener to:

```js
'tree1':{
    itemclick:  function (view, record, item, index, e) {
        if(record.data.checked==true)
        {
            console.log(record.data.id);   
        }
    }
```

I believe the listener format shown in your code is not supported.